# Salesforce OOTB Function

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

About Salesforce OOTB function
Hello everyone,

I have been working on MC construction from the beginning and am currently in the Marketing Cloud Connect stage. I am comfortable with MC Connect, but I have come across some tickets related to Salesforce OOTB functions that I am not familiar with. If any of you are acquainted with OOTB functions, could you please explain them to me?

[Journey]

MC Connect: Utilize Salesforce OOTB function for task activity; activate and test.
[Journey]

Check Journey Dashboard Salesforce OOTB function; activate and test.
[Journey]

MC Connect: Create task using Salesforce OOTB function; activate and test.

These are the conditions, but unfortunately, there are no details provided about them. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OOTB literally stands for Out Of The Box. I will assume these features cover e.g. Journey Builder activities, which will allow you to work with creating and updating records in Sales Cloud, via connector, without the need for custom development.

Full list of these activities can be found here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_sales_service_cloud_activities.htm&type=5